# RavenDB rebuilds all indexes when one document is updated

Tags: c#, ravendb

I can't seem to find an answer for this, even after Googling around.

We are experiencing issues causing our app to lock up. Partly this is because we have outstanding `WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow` calls that we are waiting to release fixes for (i.e. we have removed them) but also this is being caused by a total rebuild of all indexes. I believe the trigger that causes all indexes to be rebuilt is when we make a change to one (type of) document. For example:

We have a model called "Agency". When our users log in, we use their "AgencyId" in order to provide them with data specific to them. As such, most other documents (such as "Placements", "Invoices" etc) have an "AgencyId" field.

Agency model looks something like:

```
public class Agency
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string AgencyName {get;set;}
    // ... 
}
```

Example of `Placement` (and other Agency specific documents)

```
public class Placement
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string AgencyId {get;set;} // relates to Agency Document
    // ...
}
```

We have a feature that allows Administrators to upload documents (PDFs) to an Agency's profile. We store the PDF in a DFS and set the "DocumentPath" property on the Agency model to where it's saved.

**My question:** Would updating the Agency record cause a rebuild of *all related* documents' indexes? i.e. I know the `AgencyIndex` would rebuild but would this cause the `PlacementIndex` (and all other related indexes) to rebuild as well?

More information:
**Raven Client Build#**: 2.5.2952
**Raven Server Build#**: 2.5.2952 (RavenHQ)

Also worth noting: We are working on upgrading to RavenDB 3.0 asap but this is a real live problem and I need to understand why it's happening!

Comment: Always nice to see someone down vote and give now explanation as to why. *sigh*

Comment: I evened it out for you. I need an answer to this as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for sure updating a doc the many others points to causes the indexes to rebuild. 
Some types of operations needs the index no to be stale (or force update on stale index). It's necessary to pass a deadline to your WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow, that can receive a TimeSpan as param, so you'll wait for the index not to be stale for predefined type.

Comment: OK, Is there a way I could approach this sort of design with out having to trigger an index rebuild? Btw, I've added a TimeSpan to the WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow call but after the TimeSpan duration (60seconds) it will throw a TimeoutException and return 0 results, which is less than Ideal.

Comment: Not really. As raven points to this Doc (Agency) and all the indexes uses this docs, it really makes sense if all this indexes are rebuild.
All the point is to ensure not having stale indexes at this point.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Guess we just need to move to 3.0 ASAP!

Comment: Take a look at this doc http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.0/csharp/client-api/querying/stale-indexes